# Update Zero to One and One to Zero in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, performance, sql-server-2008

I have a table with flag 0 and 1.

Please tell me how to update Zero to One and One to  Zero

```
DECLARE @a INT, @b INT

SELECT @a = number
FROM zerone
WHERE number = 0

SELECT @b = number
FROM zerone
WHERE number = 1

BEGIN
    IF @a = 0
        UPDATE zerone
        SET number = 1
        WHERE @a = 0
    ELSE IF @b = 1
        UPDATE zerone
        SET number = 0
        WHERE @b = 1
END
```

This query is not working for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the below query to update `0` to `1` and `1` to `0`

```
update zerone set number= 1-number
```

Answer (score 1):

Just this:

```
UPDATE zerone
SET number = CASE WHEN number = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should also always consider NULL values in update operations and must explicitly filter them out

```
UPDATE zerone
SET number= case 
              when 1 then 0
              when 0 then 1
             end
WHERE number in (0,1)
```

Also your query will not work because you are assigning a single variable with a rows of data in the select statement.

```
SELECT @a = number
FROM zerone
WHERE number = 0
```

This does not work like as you are expecting and will only assign @a with value either NULL(if there are no rows) or with 0 if there is a row. If there are multiple rows even then it will have a single value 0

Answer (score 0):

As you have seen there are so many ways to perform that task but in this case, I would prefer `@Abdul Rasheed`.
We can also use below `IIF` logical function in `SQLSERVER2012 or above`.

```
UPDATE zerone
SET number = IIF (number = 1, 0, 1)
```